# Adder Implementation in Verilog?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, xilinx

In my digital electronics project I need to calculate dot product of two vectors **a** and **b** (256 length of each). Following the basic concept, I need to calculate \$ \sum_{k=1}^{256} a_kb_k \$. Each element of vectors is 4-bit binary number. This doesn't seems to a difficult task in verilog where I can implement this as in XILINX ISE.

**sum=0;**

**for(i=0,i<256,i=i+1)**

**sum=sum+ \$a_ib_i \$**

Furthur I need to implement this on FPGA. But here I got confused in two concept:

1. Do I need to write the module for 'full adder' and added the inputs previous sum and \$a_i b_i\$ bit by bit and store output in sum. Or simply xilinx will automatically implement the full adder during synthsize.
2. Is it valid to use for loop insted of writing *always@(condition)* beacause on FPGA we have clock as a control signal. Or in this case also xilinx itself will implement/control the for loop by clock signal.

Comment: Loops and HDL do not go hand in hand. Forget everything you know about procedural programming languages and start thinking in RTL.

Comment: What Xilinx tool? Xilinx is a company with many tools: ISE, Vivado, DSP tools, HLS, ... If you implement your dot-product in a loop it will synthesize but the clock frequency will be in the low MHz or kHz range! So you will need pipelining which need manual clock control / hand written HDL code.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I agree with you that I need to implement at RTl level. But do need to added the two 4-bit number bit by bit or xilinx will do it by '+' sign.

Comment: @Paebbels It's ISE.

Comment: You will need to infer a multiplier or make your own module (to calculate the \$a_i b_i\$ bit). Then you need think carefully about how to do the summation - you can infer addition using the ```+``` sign or with your own module, but is only one pair of numbers. You want to add 256 products - if you did that with a for loop you would get 256 multipliers and 256 adders which would be an incredibly long combinational path. How is your data stored?

Comment: Also, Verilog uses 0 indexing, so that for loop (which you shouldn't use) would be ```for(i=0;i<256;i=i+1)```

Comment: @TomCarpenter  I can decrease the number of bits in \$a_i and b_i$ to resolve the problem of storage. But considering the addition of high bit numbers(16,32), is it better to write your own module or go with verilog operators.

Comment: It was asking about how your data is stored, not to decrease the size, but to better recommend an approach. For example if all the numbers are in RAM, you can only read one number out at a time, in which case what you need is a MAC (multiplier-accumulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to write the module for 'full adder' and added the inputs previous sum and aibi bit by bit and store output in sum. Or simply xilinx will automatically implement the full adder during synthsize.

You can expect any decent verilog synthesis tool to handle addition and subtraction operators. Most modern ones will also handle multiplication operators. Support for division operators is less common (and when they are implemented they tend to synthisize to very large slow blocks).

Most of the time it's fine to just use the addition, subtraction and multiplication operators. For really big adders and multipliers it is sometimes nessacery to break them up into smaller units to meet timing.

> Is it valid to use for loop insted of writing always@(condition) beacause on FPGA we have clock as a control signal. Or in this case also xilinx itself will implement/control the for loop by clock signal.

synthesis tools will not turn a loop like that into sequential logic. Instead they will attempt to unroll it and implement it combinatorially. The result will be something that is both very big and very slow.